# Set value of array of input fields, by name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of input fields on my page. They're setup as an array like so:

```
<input type="text" name="test[name][]" /><br />
<input type="text" name="test[name][]" /><br />
<input type="text" name="test[name][]" /><br />
<input type="text" name="test[name][]" />
```

What i need to do next it to set a unique value in each textfield. But i don't know how to iterate over these fields with jQuery. My attempt failed: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hGTKG/)**

```
$(function() {
    $.each('input[name="test[name][]"]', function() {
        $(this).val('blaat');
    });
});
```

Any idea how i can iterate over each input field, selecting them by name!? I don't have any influence on these controls. So i **cannot** give them an extra class name or anything like that. All i have are their names.

Comment: The brackets [] are invalid characters in names of HTML elements. Valid characters are a-zA-Z0-9_:.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selector you use to get array just a is string but not array

`'input[name^="test"]'` should be `$('input[name="test[name][]"]')`

You can do it this way,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hGTKG/16/)**

```
$(function() {
    $.each($('input[name^="test[name][]"]'), function() {        
        $(this).val('blaat');
    });
});
```

​

​

Comment: `$('input[name="test[name][]"]')` should work fine too, i.e. without `^=`

Comment: how can I add an array of elements to multiple form fields that have the same class/name attributes? If I implement this method, only the first value is appended to all input fields.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
$(function() {
    $.each($('input[name^="test"]'), function() {
        $(this).val('blaat');
    });
});​
```

EDIT:
More efficient

```
$(function() {
    $('input[name^="test"]').each(function() {
        $(this).val('blaat');
    });
});​
```